# kafka could not read log4j config file from URL [file:/c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties]

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, kafka-consumer-api

I started zkper and kafka. Then I tried to run consumer and got this error.
the command i used:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic erjan --from-beginning
```

The error:

```
erjan@erjancomputer MINGW64 /c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/windows
$ kafka-console-consumer.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic erjan --from-beginning
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \c\kafka_2.12-2.8.0\bin\..\config\tools-log4j.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:557)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
        at com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$.apply(Logger.scala:48)
        at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<init>(Logging.scala:25)
        at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<clinit>(Logging.scala)
        at kafka.utils.Logging.$init$(Logging.scala:47)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:44)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.<clinit>(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/c/kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
zookeeper is not a recognized option
```

why is it not seeing config/log4j.properties?

Comment: 1) The error is actually `zookeeper is not a recognized option` 2) Why do you need to use mingw?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, i just use gitbash, it uses mingw. i guess it does not matter here.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, how do i make it recognize zookeper?

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: You cannot use Zookeeper to consume from topics. Unclear what documentation you're following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j file cannot be found because, I guess, mingw or similar shell environments in Windows aren't really tested in the Kafka source code. That's why there's `.bat` scripts instead. If you want to use a Linux shell, uninstall Git Bash and use WSL2

Besides that, it's irrelevant to the actual error. You need to use `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` instead of the Zookeeper flag in order to consume from Kafka.

Refer the official documentation (which is for Linux), but the command arguments are all the same, even if you use the windows scripts

http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: actually u re right, i did manage to launch simplest console producer /consumer yesterday. but now i m facing issue with another cmd. will ask in separate question

Answer (score 2):

In your case, two dots in the path are being interpreted incorrectly. I'm assuming you're running sh on Windows. These two points are specified in the kafka-run-class.sh file in this variable:

```
base_dir=$(dirname $0)/..
```

And then this variable is used here:

```
LOG4J_DIR="$base_dir/config/tools-log4j.properties"
```

Two dots mean that you need to take the directory above the directory where sh is located, i.e. higher than bin, i.e. kafka root directory. But you have these two points interpreted as they are. As a solution, you can do this - it will have the same meaning:

```
LOG4J_DIR="config/tools-log4j.properties"
```

Or run bat as written above